# CORS ERROR: I have a Laravel project that i'm posting from a HTML form and an Ajax request to the Laravel 10 server route. Which gets rejected by CORS

Tags: laravel, cors

I have a Laravel project that i am posting to from a remote server using an HTML form and an Ajax request to the Laravel 10 server route. Which gets rejected by CORS

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://egrdev.au/enquiry' from origin 'https://egr.net.au' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have this codebase working perfectly on my development server but when I upload it to the live server it gets CORS issues.

The Ajax form data POST code is:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            }); 

   $.ajax({
      url: 'https://egrdev.au/enquiry',
      method: 'POST',
      
      data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        subject: subject,
        content: content
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log('Success:', response);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    });
  }
```

The Cors.php file

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['https://egr.net.au'],

    //'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

    //'allowed_headers' => ['Accept', 'Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];
```

The CorsMiddleware.php

````
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application', 'ip', 'X-Auth-Token', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN');
        return $response; 
    }
}```


The Kernel.php
````

```
protected $middleware = [ // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class, \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class, \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class, \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class, \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class, \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class, \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class, \App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class, \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class, ];
```

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: Add SSL to this domain ```https://egrdev.au/``` then only it will allow you to access data

Comment: You shouldn't manually set CORS response headers _in addition_ to a applying Laravel's CORS middleware. Instead, just use the latter. CORS middleware shouldn't be stacked/combined.